# Get-WinEvent most recent 1 event only?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I get the most recent WinEvent with specific event ID?

Script:

```
$EventID = 4728
$groups = @("Domain Admins", "Enterprise Admins", "Schema Admins")

$Results = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing $($_) ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $Event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ LogName = 'Security'; Id = $EventID; } -ComputerName $_
    
    Write-Host "`t Events $($Event) ..." -ForegroundColor Red
    
    # Loop through each group and check to see if the event contained that group
    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        if ($Event.Message -like "*$group*")
        {
            # Event contains a critical group
            $Event.Message + "`r`n`t" + $Event.TimeGenerated
        }
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

Because with the above code, What I received is a blank email message and this error on the console:

> Events System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord System.
> Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord System.Diagnost
> ics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Even ting.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord ...

Comment: It's not an error. These are your received event records. You should not ouptut them with `Write-Host` with the foreground color  red!!

Comment: @Olaf yes, thank you.